# How to access GPU from Ubuntu 22 VM running in Virtual Box on Windows 10?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gpu

I have an HP ZBook 17 G6 with 2 GPUs:

- GPU 0: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
- GPU 1: NVIDIA Quadro T1000

It's running Win 10. I created an Ubuntu 22 VM in Virtualbox but I can't figure out how to get it to access the Nvidia GPU. I added the VB exe to the list of apps in the NVidia control panel but that didn't help. What else do I need to do? TIA!

Comment: You need to understand how virtualization works. Then you'll understand that what you want can't be done. GPU passtrough is possible only when you have 2 independent graphics cards, not 
 a laptop's hybrid switchable graphics.

Comment: Is the Nvidia card default in the host system? If not, try making it default, restart, and test

Comment: @John It doesn't matter. Virtualbox by default only does virtual GPU. What I explained above was to clarify that unlike many people think switchable graphics don't allow both cards to be active at the same time, the condition required for reserving one for the host and passing the other to the VM.

Comment: If course you cannot attach the hardware device in a VM, but if the NVidia card is default, VBOX may use it as the VBOX video card.  Worth trying I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualbox does not provide to the VM direct access (passthrough)
to the host GPU. However, Virtualbox does provide 3D acceleration
through Guest Additions, which accelerates some VM graphics by running
them on the host.

For GPU passthrough on a Windows host, you need to use Hyper-V.
If you're interested in going in this direction, here are two
articles to get you started:

- [Running GPU passthrough for a virtual desktop with Hyper-V](https://www.techtarget.com/searchvirtualdesktop/tip/Running-GPU-passthrough-for-a-virtual-desktop-with-Hyper-V)
- [Tutorial: Passing through GPU to Hyper-V guest VM](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/195745-tutorial-passing-through-gpu-hyper-v-guest-vm.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GPU_passthrough_with_libvirt_qemu_kvm

https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/13.0/grid-vgpu-release-notes-generic-linux-kvm/index.html#release-notes

I know virtualbox could use `kvm` or `qemu` as their backend.

kvm or qemu supports gpu passthrough, but virtualbox doesn't seems to have this feature for now.